# Is it possible to mark a test with an 'owner' and log that owner when the test fails?

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to mark each test (or maybe just each file) with a test owner. When a test fails, i'd like to include a print statement with the owner. Is anything like this possible with default pytest functionality? I can't figure out any way to tell if a test fails or not which is the first major step to this.

I figure I can either add a customer mark or just a custom decorator for the owner, though i'm also wondering if pytest supports this in some better way. So what i'm looking for is something like this:

```
@test_owner("user1", "user1@company.com")
def test_foo():
    pass
```

Then if the test fails, just print something like:

"user1: user1@company.com", so that someone looking at a failed build can quickly figure out who to contact.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no implementation of such functionality, so probably you have to make your own [mark](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs) and the [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures) which prints owner on failure.